# how to check if string has server ih php

Tags: php, function, url

How to check if string has a server depending if url is absolute or relative?

```
function hasServer($url){
    ...
}
```

If this, returns true

```
hasServer('http://www.google.com/');
```

else return false

```
hasServer('/about-us/team/');
```

Comment: what do you mean "if string has a server"?

Comment: Do you mean if the `$url` is an active url online? please correct your question so that it is more clear.

Comment: i mean if has a substring like www.google.com (is absolute url) or there is no "server" string (is relative url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$url = 'http://www.google.com/';
$hasServer = filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
```

Comment: why did you go and change it to single quotes from [my edited](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37120937/2) double quotes? I don't see the improvement here and if there should be a variable passed inside single quotes and the OP wants to pass, your answer will fail

Comment: @Fred-ii- why would you use double quotes on a string literal? It is bad practice in general so it should be avoided. If the OP puts a variable inside single quotes then that's his mistake and he learns one more thing.
I didn't know your edit would disappear from history, did you lose rep for that?

Answer (score 1):

There are actually a few options from my experience. One would be to use the `headers()` function and then to analyse what information you obtained inside the resulting array.

```
$arrayResult = headers('http://www.google.com/');
foreach ($arrayResult as $value)
{
  echo "-- ".$value."<br>";
}
```

The output should give you all the information you need regarding if the url actually exists.

A simpler solution in my opinion is to  just check if the `fopen()` function actually works on the url!

```
if (fopen('http://www.google.com/', "r")
{
  echo "the URL exists!<br>";
}
```

You can choose which one servers your needs better.

Comment: `headers('http://www.google.com/);` missing something here. (quote)